# Something is wrong with the header "WICTextureLoader.h"

Tags: c++

Everytime I include the header `WICTextureLoader.h` and the `WICTextureLoader.cpp`, i get the compiler error `redefinition of default argument: parameter 1, note: see declaration of 'DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile`. This error shows up 4 times in the `WICTextureLoader.h` and it tells me that the functions `CreateWICTextureFromMemory` and `CreateWICTextureFromFile` all have redefinitions of their first parameter.

Down below is me using the functions..

```
#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>   //I also used the functions in this header in my application 
#include <WICTextureLoader.h>
#include <WICTextureLoader.cpp>

CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, DevContext, L"grass.jpg", NULL, &Texture, 0);
```

I assume the first parameter of the function is invalid? or maybe the function doesn't load .jpg files?

What am i supposed to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the `.cpp` file at the top of your program.  Only the header should be included, and only once.

Comment: I already tried that. If i only include the header, the compiler shows the typical "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" error. (P.S i downloaded the file online, i didn't make it myself)

Comment: If you downloaded it online, then you'll need to add the `WICTextureLoader.cpp` file as if it were another part of your program.  I haven't used VS in a while, but I think you may need to enclose the file name in quotes instead of angle brackets.

Comment: The error is still there. I placed the .cpp file in the same directive as my application and enclosed the file name with quotes